# Angular model-driven forms: Set custom validator in 'setValidators()'

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

This is a small question, but it's has bothering me.

I have a scene where I get a value (let's say a boolean) from outside the form, meaning it is not part of formgroup. And based on that value I want to set a custom validator, as it does not apply with the available ones (`required`,`pattern`...) Here is a **very** simplified code to showcase:
So the problem is easy to set a required validator like so:

```
if(bool) {
   this.myForm.get('field').setValidators([Validators.required])
   this.myForm.get('field').updateValueAndValidity();
} else ....
```

I would like a way to set a custom validation error instead. So something like:

```
 this.myForm.get('field').setValidators([{notValid: true}])
```

But the above don't work, but I need to do that instead:

```
 this.myForm.get('field').setValidators([this.customValidator])

 customValidator(field) {
   return {notValid: true}
 }
```

Is it not possible to set a custom validation on one line, instead of needing to having `customValidator`? (or any other better way)

I know, small problem, but it's has been bothering me and code is also actually more complex than here.

PS. I know I could do it and use for example one of the available Validators to mark it as invalid, but I would like clean solution if is possible.

Comment: Have you tried `(field) =>  {notValid: true}`? Seems it looks like one line. You can also use `setErrors`

Comment: Well.. in my opinion, according to the case you described, you don't need `setValidators`, but `setErros` *method*... `<control>.setErrors({notValid: true})`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, a lambda can turn that into a one-liner, with the caveat that its return value cannot start with a `{` or else it'll be seen as a function body, so prepend a type-cast like `<any>`

`this.myForm.get('field').setValidators(f => <any>{notValid:true})`

Secondly, if the custom validation is conditional on state outside of the form, you may consider moving that boolean check into the validator itself.

`.setValidators(f => outsideBoolean ? {notValid:true} : null)`

But you still must run `updateValueAndValidity()` yourself when outsideBoolean changes.  Not even as a cross-field validator will the form update itself automatically.

Alternately, don't use angular/forms at all for that boolean.

A 3rd way: use a `<input type="hidden"` and put the outsideBoolean into that, so it does participate in the form validation machinery.